# How to automate the creation of repo in ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

`docker push` cannot push the docker image to ECR, because the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html) says,

> If your image repository does not exist in the registry you intend to push to yet, **create it**. For more information, see [Creating a Repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-create.html).

---

Repository creation procedure given in the above link provides manual procedure via AWS console.

How to create repo in ECR using AWS CLI?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ecr cli to create a repository. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/create-repository.html

Answer (score 2):

the only way to automate it using the command line.
You can try below command to create a repo using AWS CLI.

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name project-a/my-web-app
```

Hope this would help you
Happy automating :-)